# UWP C#: The name xxx cannot be found in namespace yyy

Tags: c#, uwp, namespaces

I am developing a UWP application using C# and MVVM.  Yesterday, I ran the app to test recent changes, and all was fine.  Later in the day, I fired up the laptop, opened VS, and now converters and controls are flagging.  Intellisense recognizes and will autofill the namespace and the particular converter, but then gives the blue squiggly line saying it cannot be found.  The same happens with controls.

When I try to compile, I get errors saying "The name 'DecimalToTextConverter' does not exist in the namespace 'using.POSClient.Converters' although it clearly does.

[Screenshot of the error(s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3nYs.png)

I have searched for two days looking for an answer to this, and tried all of the suggestions -- primarily changing the target platform back and forth, and closing and opening VS, along with rebooting several times, and even a rollback to a restore point two days before the issue began.

I do not believe I made any code or setting changes between a viable working code base and the onset of this issue.

I'm stumped.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the "using:" from all of your namespace definitions.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelC. for the suggestion.  I tried it and it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the fix is for this problem, but I did an undo on all changes that had not yet been committed and the error is gone.  If it returns, I will update this post with anything new I learn.